# Nothing happens when launching some snap apps

Tags: snap

I'm attempting to use the Office365WebDesktop snap. The snap apparently installs successfully from the Snap Store and an icon appears in my application list but nothing happens when I try to run it. I have the same issue with other web-based snap apps.

If I try to run Office365WebDesktop by clicking an icon, it briefly appears in the Task Manager before exiting. No windows appear. If I try launching from the terminal, nothing launches and I get no error messages:

```
:~$ office365webdesktop 
:~$
```

I have also tried running `snap run --debug-log office365webdesktop`; I don't see any relevant error messages. I've included the output at the end of this question.

Other snap apps I've tried with the same result are: GoldenDictionary, OneNote Desktop, p3x-onenote. Snaps like Chromium and Audacity run without problems. Any help getting Office365WebDesktop to work would be greatly appreciated!

Output of `snap run --debug-log office365webdesktop`:

```
2023/01/18 09:03:02.224266 cmd_run.go:488: DEBUG: enabled debug logging of early snap startup
2023/01/18 09:03:02.224462 cmd_run.go:1037: DEBUG: executing snap-confine from /snap/snapd/17950/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
2023/01/18 09:03:02.224769 cmd_run.go:440: DEBUG: SELinux not enabled
2023/01/18 09:03:02.224990 tracking.go:46: DEBUG: creating transient scope snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop
2023/01/18 09:03:02.225389 tracking.go:186: DEBUG: using session bus
2023/01/18 09:03:02.226162 tracking.go:319: DEBUG: create transient scope job: /org/freedesktop/systemd1/job/1617
2023/01/18 09:03:02.226569 tracking.go:419: DEBUG: job result is "done"
2023/01/18 09:03:02.226575 tracking.go:426: DEBUG: transient scope snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop.3c530350-237e-4219-a855-99de4082ec25.scope created
2023/01/18 09:03:02.226697 tracking.go:146: DEBUG: waited 1.271622ms for tracking
2023/01/18 09:03:02.226703 logger.go:184: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap to snap-confine", "time":"1674061382.226701"}
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine enter", "time":"1674061382.227596"}
DEBUG: umask reset, old umask was   02
DEBUG: security tag: snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop
DEBUG: executable:   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec
DEBUG: confinement:  non-classic
DEBUG: base snap:    core18
DEBUG: ruid: 1000, euid: 0, suid: 0
DEBUG: rgid: 1000, egid: 1000, sgid: 1000
DEBUG: apparmor label on snap-confine is: /snap/snapd/17950/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
DEBUG: apparmor mode is: enforce
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine mount namespace start", "time":"1674061382.227803"}
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope (global), uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: ensuring that snap mount directory is shared
DEBUG: unsharing snap namespace directory
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: releasing lock 5
DEBUG: opened snap-update-ns executable as file descriptor 5
DEBUG: opened snap-discard-ns executable as file descriptor 6
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/office365webdesktop.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope office365webdesktop, uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: initializing mount namespace: office365webdesktop
DEBUG: setting up device cgroup
DEBUG: libudev has current tags support
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0 has matching current tag
DEBUG: get bpf object at path /sys/fs/bpf/snap/snap_office365webdesktop_office365webdesktop
DEBUG: found existing device map
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: found 24 existing entries in devices map
DEBUG: delete key for c 195:254
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 226:128
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 136:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 10:239
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 510:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 226:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 140:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 141:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 10:200
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:2
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 137:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:3
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 195:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 195:255
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:8
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 142:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:9
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 139:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:7
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 138:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:5
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 143:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: load program of type 0xf, 33 instructions
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:3
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:5
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:7
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:8
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:9
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:1
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:2
DEBUG: v2 allow c 136:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 137:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 138:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 139:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 140:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 141:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 142:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 143:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 195:0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 195:255
DEBUG: v2 allow c 510:0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 195:254
DEBUG: v2 allow c 10:239
DEBUG: v2 allow c 10:200
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dri/card0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 226:0
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-2 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-2
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-2 has matching current tag
DEBUG: cannot get major/minor numbers for syspath /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-2
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0/drm/renderD128 has matching current tag
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/dri/renderD128
DEBUG: v2 allow c 226:128
DEBUG: process in cgroup /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop.3c530350-237e-4219-a855-99de4082ec25.scope
DEBUG: cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup//user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop.3c530350-237e-4219-a855-99de4082ec25.scope opened at 10
DEBUG: attach type 0x6 program 9 to cgroup 10
DEBUG: associated snap application process 18689 with device cgroup snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop
DEBUG: forked support process 18714
DEBUG: changing apparmor hat to mount-namespace-capture-helper
DEBUG: helper process waiting for command
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: block device of snap core18, revision 2667 is 7:10
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: joining preserved mount namespace for inspection
DEBUG: found base snap device 7:10 on /
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: preserved mount is not stale, reusing
DEBUG: joined preserved mount namespace office365webdesktop
DEBUG: joining preserved per-user mount namespace
DEBUG: unsharing the mount namespace (per-user)
DEBUG: sc_setup_user_mounts: office365webdesktop
DEBUG: performing operation: (disabled) use debug build to see details
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: calling snapd tool snap-update-ns
DEBUG: waiting for snapd tool snap-update-ns to terminate
DEBUG: requesting changing of apparmor profile on next exec to snap-update-ns.office365webdesktop
change.go:522: DEBUG: current mount entries
change.go:522: DEBUG: desired mount entries (sorted)
change.go:524: DEBUG: - /run/user/1000/doc/by-app/snap.office365webdesktop /run/user/1000/doc none bind,rw,x-snapd.ignore-missing 0 0
change.go:604: DEBUG: desiredIDs: map[/run/user/1000/doc:true]
change.go:605: DEBUG: reuse: map[]
change.go:662: DEBUG: processing mount entries
change.go:656: DEBUG: adding independent entry: /run/user/1000/doc/by-app/snap.office365webdesktop /run/user/1000/doc none bind,rw,x-snapd.ignore-missing 0 0
change.go:724: DEBUG: all mimics:
change.go:522: DEBUG: mount entries ordered as they will be applied
change.go:524: DEBUG: - /run/user/1000/doc/by-app/snap.office365webdesktop /run/user/1000/doc none bind,rw,x-snapd.ignore-missing 0 0
change.go:320: DEBUG: mount name:"/run/user/1000/doc/by-app/snap.office365webdesktop" dir:"/run/user/1000/doc" type:"none" opts:MS_BIND unparsed:"" (error: <nil>)
DEBUG: snap-update-ns finished successfully
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: NOT preserving per-user mount namespace
DEBUG: releasing lock 7
DEBUG: sending command 0 to helper process (pid: 18714)
DEBUG: waiting for response from helper
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: helper process received command 0
DEBUG: helper process exiting
DEBUG: waiting for the helper process to exit
DEBUG: helper process exited normally
DEBUG: resetting PATH to values in sync with core snap
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine mount namespace finish", "time":"1674061382.232452"}
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:1000 (change: yes), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: creating user data directory: /home/$USER/snap/office365webdesktop/4
DEBUG: requesting changing of apparmor profile on next exec to snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop
DEBUG: ruid: 1000, euid: 1000, suid: 0
DEBUG: setting capabilities bounding set
DEBUG: regaining SYS_ADMIN
DEBUG: loading bpf program for security tag snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop
DEBUG: read 6408 bytes from /var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf//snap.office365webdesktop.office365webdesktop.bin
DEBUG: read 152 bytes from /var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf/global.bin
DEBUG: clearing SYS_ADMIN
DEBUG: execv(/usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec, /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec...)
DEBUG:  argv[1] = office365webdesktop
DEBUG: umask restored to   02
DEBUG: working directory restored to /home/$USER
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine to snap-exec", "time":"1674061382.233353"}
2023/01/18 09:03:02.237705 logger.go:184: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-exec to app", "time":"1674061382.237703"}
```

Comment: I had similar problem when the 6.0 kernel was installed. I changed to 6.1 and it was fixed.